# Dividing List by integer and checking if any element in list is integer (PYTHON)

Tags: python-2.7, floating-point, integer, division

Hey I am a beginner at python, I wrote this code but its not working, i'm sure its something small that I cant see.

```
    myList = [10,22,30,40]
    myInt = 3.0
    newList = [x/myInt for x in myList]
    if any(isinstance(y,int) for y in newList):
        print newList
    else:
        print "None are integers"
```

Since 30/3 =10 and 10 is integer, it should print out newList which is [3.33, 7.33, 10.0, 13.33], but its printing "None are integers".

I am certain there is a problem with "if any(isinstance(y,int) for y in newList):" but cannot figure out what.

Comment: `newList` items are floats.

Comment: `3.0` is also not an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2.7+, you can check to see if a `float` can be represented as an `int`:

```
myList = [10,22,30,40]
myInt = 3.0

divided = (el / myInt for el in myList) # generator over floats
is_integer = [el for el in divided if el.is_integer()] # filter ints only
# [10.0]
```

So your check would be:

```
if any((el / myInt).is_integer() for el in myList):
    # do something
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your basic problem:

```
>>> 30/3
10
>>> 30/3.0
10.0
>>> type(10.0)
<type 'float'>
```

An integer is a whole number, without a fractional component. A float is a number, but with a fractional component (a decimal point), even if its `.0` as the case above.

Although they are both numbers, for Python they are two different *types*.

Since you are dividing by a float, all results will be floats. Therefore your check fails because although they are *numbers* they are not *integers*.

Answer (score 0):

Type is a strict feature in Python. Any operation involving a float produces another float, even if the value *could* be represented exactly as an integer. Something like this might work for you:

```
myList = [10,22,30,40]
myInt = 3
newList = [x%myInt for x in myList] # A list of remainders now, not quotients
if any(y == 0 for y in newList):
    print [ x/(1.0*myInt) for x in myList ]   # Reproduce your original myList 
else:
    print "None are integers"
```